# Single word for 'their own fault'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am searching for a single word that has a definition similar to the phrase 'their own fault'.

I am unaware of a *single* word bearing this definition, possibly culpable or blameworthy but believe there may be alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please include an example sentence or two where the word or phrase would be used. There is a tag "single-word-request" and you can click on it to find out how to ask a good SWR question. http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info I will edit your question for the tag. Good luck.

Comment: If you switch the point of view slightly, you could use *negligent*.

Answer (score 5):

You could go for [*self-inflicted*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-inflicted):

> caused by one's own actions
>
> - a self-inflicted wound
> - His problems are mainly self-inflicted.

Comment: This is probably as close as anyone is going to get. +1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [onus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onus):

> Responsibility for an error or fault; blame: Each side wants to avoid the *onus* of having started the disagreement.